SwiftUI TabView inside NavigationStack adds extra spacing, I only want my toolbar item there but it also adds invisible spacing
So I have this view called HomeView()
var body: some View {
        Text("hi")
        
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
        .toolbar{
            /// Find better fix instead of giving each one of these top padding
            /// Search bar
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement:.principal){
                Text("hi")
            }
            
          
            
                
                
            }
        
        .toolbarBackground(.white, for: .navigationBar)
        
            
    }

and then my ContentView
{
            TabView{
                HomeView()
                    .tabItem{
                        VStack{
                            Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                            
                                .foregroundStyle(.red)
                            Text("Home")
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .toolbarBackground(Color.pink, for: .navigationBar)

                   

                HomeView()
                    .tabItem{
                        VStack{
                            Image(systemName: "person.2.fill")
                            Text("My Network")
                        }
                        .foregroundStyle(selectedTab == .network ? .black : .shuttleGray)
                    }
                HomeView()
                    .tabItem{
                        VStack{
                            Image(systemName: "plus.app.fill")
                            Text("Post")
                        }
                        .foregroundStyle(selectedTab == .post ? .black : .shuttleGray)
                    }
                HomeView()
                    .tabItem{
                        VStack{
                            Image(systemName: "bell.fill")
                                .rotationEffect(selectedTab == .notifications ? .degrees(45) : .zero)
                            Text("Notifications")
                        }
                    }
                    .badge(3)
                JobsView()
                    .tabItem{
                        VStack{
                            Image(systemName: "latch.2.case.fill")
                            Text("Jobs")
                        }
                        .foregroundStyle(selectedTab == .jobs ? .black : .shuttleGray)
                    }
            }
            
            
            .tint(.black)
        }


The problem is it seems the TabView adds this extra space, I only want my toolbar item to be visible and not all that extra space below, if I hide the toolbar it will fix this but obviously also remove my Text I put in the toolbar, if I change the order and make it so the NavigationStack is inside the TabView I then run into other issues where if disable the TabView and make it hidden in a specific view then pop back to the previous view the TabView is delayed when it comes back.
Any ideas? No clue how to fix this.
I had two comments saying this is why TabView should be at the top and each view should have its own NavigationStack, now I brought this up too but the new issue is this:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView{
            NavigationStack{
                NavigationLink("Hi"){
                    Text("New view! If I go back the TabView will now be delayed when it reappears")
                    /// Lets say for this specific view I no longer want the TabView to be visible
                    /// When dismissing it and going back the TabView on the bottom will now be very slow to reappear
                        .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                }
                    
            }
            .tabItem{
                Text("Tab")
            }
           
        }
        
    }
}

Is there any other way to make the TabView not glitchy and slow when it reappears when I navigate back? It works if I do the opposite(TabView inside NavigationStack) it won't be laggy

TabView should be at the top. Each tab must have its own NavigationStack

Agree.  It would be very unusual for a tab view to be in a navigation stack.  You want each tab to have its own navigation stack

Can you guys check the edit? I now run into a new issue where the TabView appears very slowly when navigating back

Try switching to navigationDestination, the older ways of navigating have a ton of bugs.
